# how to install php-pear-Net-SMTP in centos 6.x?

Tags: php, centos

I want to install php-pear-Net-SMTP with yum , but when i enter

```
yum install php-pear-Net-SMTP
```

i receive this

```
No package php-pear-Net-SMTP available.
```

so how can i install php-pear-Net-SMT in centos 6.x

i use centos 6.3

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sudo pear install Net_SMTP
```

You may also want to install `mail` using

```
pear install mail
```